# how to set a different slide transition effect for the slide by use apache poi

Tags: java, apache, apache-poi, powerpoint

I am doing a function recently,use `apache poi` to exporting `powerpoint`,
I want to set a different slide transition effect for the slide, but I can't find any method in the `apache api`, has anyone ever done anything like this?

 Please tell me , thank you !

My English is not very good. I hope you can read it. XD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing for setting transitions in [XSLFSlide](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/xslf/usermodel/XSLFSlide.html) and [XSLFSheet](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/xslf/usermodel/XSLFSheet.html) until now. So we would need using the underlying low level objects of  `ooxml-schemas-1.4`.  Unfortunately there is no documentation for `ooxml-schemas` public available. That's why we need downloading the [sources](http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/poi/ooxml-schemas/1.4/) and doing `javadoc` from them.

Then we find `CTSlide` having `addNewTransition()` and `CTSlideTransition` having different transition elements for example  "blinds" element, "checker" element, "circle" element, ...

Example:

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

import org.apache.poi.xslf.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.sl.usermodel.*;

import java.awt.Color;

public class CreatePPTXSheetsTransition {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  XMLSlideShow slideShow = new XMLSlideShow();
  XSLFSlide slide = slideShow.createSlide();
  if (slide.getXmlObject().getCSld().getBg() == null) slide.getXmlObject().getCSld().addNewBg();
  slide.getBackground().setFillColor(Color.BLUE);
  slide.getXmlObject().addNewTransition().addNewDissolve();
  slide = slideShow.createSlide();
  if (slide.getXmlObject().getCSld().getBg() == null) slide.getXmlObject().getCSld().addNewBg();
  slide.getBackground().setFillColor(Color.RED);
  slide.getXmlObject().addNewTransition().addNewWheel().setSpokes(8);

  FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("CreatePPTXSheetsTransition.pptx");
  slideShow.write(out);
  out.close();
 }
}
```